# React. Импорт svg

Tags: reactjs, svg, typescript

Экспортирую SVG из файла `index.ts`

```
import * as upArrow from "./up-arrow.svg";
import * as downArrow from "./down-arrow.svg";

export { upArrow, downArrow };
```

Затем использую в компоненте

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Icon } from "components";
import { upArrow, downArrow } from "common/assets";

const CollapseIcon = ({ condition }) => (
  <Icon alternative={upArrow} asset={downArrow} condition={condition} />
);

export default CollapseIcon;
```

Если это важно, я использую значения `asset` и `alternative` в `src` атрибуте

```
export default styled.img.attrs<IconProps>({
  src: ({ condition, alternative, asset }: IconProps) =>
    condition ? alternative : asset,
  alt: ({ alt }: IconProps) => alt
})`
  vertical-align: middle;
 `
```

В итоге получаю HTML-элемент с некорректным значением аттрибута `src`, если убираю лишние кавычки, элемент отображается корректно. Где допускаю ошибку?

[image: кусок разметки в отладчике]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить `.svg` расширение в лист расширений `url-loader`

```js
...
rules: [
...
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/, /\.svg$/],
            loader: require.resolve("url-loader"),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
            }
          },
...
```

Comment: прошло 2 дня, вы можете, если захотите отметить свой ответ зеленой галочкой. Баллов это вам не добавит, но зато вопрос будет отмечен, как решенный

Comment: @while1pass А можно подробнее? Где находится это лист расширений и как он обычно выглядит?

Comment: @Arantler это конфигурация webpack, подробнее здесь https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/